# "Share Calendar" button greyed out in Outlook 2010

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook-2010, calendar

I´m trying to share a calendar using Outlook 2010 but the button is greyed out.

I can share it without problems if I use Outlook 2007

I´m running Outlook 2010 against a 2003 Exchange server.

How can I share it using 2010 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check inheritance is checked under the security properties of the user (in AD).

Also check full permission given on that mailbox to 'Self'.

Comment: Great thanks it worked. Sorry for the late response, forgot to accept the answer after I tested it

Answer (score 0):

In our case, the user was creating the calendar by mistake under a different account. Recreated the calendar under his account and the button appeared.

Right Click on one of the Calendars > Create New Calendar > make sure to select Calendars that is under the user's account.